# CQ5 - Sling accessing nodes

Tags: java, aem, sling

I'm a complete newb to this so I apologize in advance. I've got an instance of CQ5 set up 
and I can't figure out how to access specific nodes. So say I have a component with the 
path:
    **/project/components/content/leftsidebar**
but I want to access properties of another node here:
    **/content/dam/campaign**

I know the properties.get method works but only if your within that node
**properties.get("title", "placeholder");**

I'm a complete newb so please post code samples were possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd want to use the `ResourceResolver` in order to get the resource that you're looking for. From there, you can adapt it to a `ValueMap` & read its properties:

```
ResourceResolver resourceResolver = slingRequest.getResourceResolver();
Resource campaignResource = resourceResolver.getResource("/content/dam/campaign");
ValueMap campaignProperties = campaignResource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class);
String title = campaignProperties.get("title", "placeholder");
```

You can read more about accessing properties on the [**Apache Sling** website](http://sling.apache.org/site/getting-resources-and-properties-in-sling.html). Remember, CQ5 is Sling under the hood, so it's a great resource & you're still a level of abstraction above accessing the JCR directly.

Comment: Thanks for replying @anotherdave.  Any idea why I'm getting this error: **ResourceResolver cannot be resolved to a type** do I need to include an additional package?  Sorry I'm a complete newb to this stuff.

Comment: You need to import the org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver interface in your script.

Comment: Thanks @bertrand any reason why I would be getting this error **Duplicate local variable resourceResolver**

Comment: hey @anotherdave happen to know why I would be getting a **Duplicate local variable resourceResolver** thanks!

Comment: @Demon Young. I'd say most likely you've a reference to "cq:defineObjects" or "sling:defineObjects" in your script or one you're including. These already expose a "resourceResolver" variable so you wouldn't need to declare it. More info here - https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/howto/taglib.html#%3Csling:defineObjects%3E